# twig recursive function in Twig_SimpleFunction

Tags: php, twig

I need to know how to call a function defined within $twig-> addFunction (new Twig_SimpleFunction from the same function or recursively.
Thank you very much!
Pablo

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried, what you expected it to do, and what it actually did. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by passing down the `twig` instance towards the callable inside the `Twig_SimleFunction`

```
$twig->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('fibonacci', function($n) use($twig) {
    if ($n == 0) return 0;
    if ($n == 1) return 1;

    $fn = $twig->getFunction('fibonacci')->getCallable();
    return $fn($n -1) + $fn($n - 2);
}));
```

---

It would be much simpler if you would use an extension class, rather than trying to do recursion without it.

With an extension class you could simply do it like this

```
class Project_Twig_Extension extends Twig_Extension {
    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new Twig_Function('fibonacci', array($this, 'fibonacci')),
        );
    }

    private function fibonacci($n) {
        if ($n == 0) return 0;
        if ($n == 1) return 1;
        return $this->fibonacci($n -1) + $this->fibonacci($n - 2);      
    }
}
```

---

*note* To register an extension to `twig`, just do:

```
$twig->addExtension(new Project_Twig_Extension());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! It was very useful!